# check identity of multiple users on actions on google

Tags: python-3.x, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I have successfully implemented google assistant on rpi using gassistpi and added agent on dialogflow also. The issue is that if multiple users invoke google assistant on different raspberry pi I am not able to identify which user has invoked the action as request from webhook on dialogflow doesn't have any user identity information. Thus, I am facing issues while retrieving data for particular user.

I tried using account linking on actions on google using google signup over voice but I am unable to implement that.

Comment: can we change the format of request sent to google assistant after recognising speech

Answer (score 1):

The Google Assistant SDK does not have voice match as a feature, so you would be unable to use it to identify individual users of the Action on that surface.

Answer (score -1):

when your webhook is called, you have the ability to store data from every request.   For instance look at :

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data

That way you can maintain and know each devices session.  Even if you don't know the user.